# What are some solutions for modeling the human body

Tags: 3d, hardware, 3d-modelling

Ideally, I'm looking for some sort of software component which takes as input the location of a few sensors spread across the body, and outputs a full body position.

Thanks!

Comment: what you really want? do you want to design a 3D human body? or something else

Answer (score 0):

[Motionbuilder](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/index?id=13581855&siteID=123112) maybe?